# How to set '₹' symbol in input text box by Jquery in IE 8?

Tags: jquery

Jquery + html

```
$("#amount").val("₹" + 500 + " - ₹" + 600);
```

This code is working fine in mozilla and google chrome but in IE 8 it is showing box,,,
How to fix this into IE.

Any solution/help...

Comment: What is the charset your document have? `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` for older IE browsers.

Comment: charset of mine document <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

Comment: it does not have `charset`?

Comment: so what i need to give there jai..

Comment: @jai i have given <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> also but not working...